# Spark scala cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Please see the below code and let me know where I am doing it wrong?

Using:

DSE Version - 5.1.0

Connected to Test Cluster at 172.31.16.45:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10.0.1652 | DSE 5.1.0 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.

Thanks

```
Cassandra Table :
cqlsh:tdata> select * from map;

 sno | name
-----+------
   1 |  One
   2 |  Two
```

### -------------------------------------------

scala> :showSchema tdata
    ========================================
     Keyspace: tdata
    ========================================
     Table: map
    ----------------------------------------
     - sno  : Int    (partition key column)
     - name : String

scala> val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("tdata", "map")

scala> rdd.foreach(println)

I am not getting anything here?
Not even an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit a very common spark issue. Your `println` code is being executed on your remote `executor` JVMs. That means the printout is to the `STDOUT` of the `executor` JVM process. If you want to bring the data back to the `driver` JVM before printing you need a `collect` call.

```
rdd
 .collect //Change from RDD to local collection
 .foreach(println)
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you about that.